# Creating an Angular User "Security" service

Tags: angular

I'm trying to create a security service for use in my Angular app and am running into a problem where it is calling the back-end end API (which is where it determines what permissions a user has) numerous times, but I only want it to call that once and everyone else to piggy-back on that one request.

What I have is in numerous places throughout the UI I have things like this

```
<button pButton type="button" class="ui-button-warning" (click)="customPointsDisplay=true" icon="fa fa-plus"
    style="margin-top: 8px" [disabled]="disabled" *ngIf="securityService.isAdmin() | async"></button>
```

The key point of that line is the *ngIf line where it calls a component to check if the person is an admin or some other security level.  This is done with the async because I want these to trigger the call to load the information (if needed).

Then in the Security Service component I have the following code.

```
loadSecurity(): Observable<void> {
    if (!this.loading) {
        this.loading = this.http.get(this.baseApiUrl + `loadSecurity`)
            .map((result) => {
                var data = this.extractData(result);
                this.isAdminUser = data.IsAdmin;
                this.isCommercializationTeamUser = data.IsCommercializationTeam;
                this.isRedTeamUser = data.IsRedTeam;
                this.isBlueTeamUser = data.IsBlueTeam;
                this.isVisitorUser = data.IsVisitor;
                this.isProjectOwnerTeamUser = data.IsProjectOwnerTeam;
                this.isProjectTeamUser = data.IsProjectUserTeam;
                this.isSensoryInsightsTeamUser = data.IsSensoryInsightsTeam;
            });
    }

    return this.loading;
}

checkSecurity(whichUser: string): Observable<boolean> {
    return Observable.create((observer: any) => {
        if ((this as any)[whichUser] !== undefined) {
            observer.next((this as any)[whichUser]);
            observer.complete();
        } else {
            this.loadSecurity()
                .subscribe(() => {
                    observer.next((this as any)[whichUser]);
                    observer.complete();
                },
                (error: any) => this.handleError(error));
        }
    });
}

isAdmin(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.checkSecurity('isAdminUser');
}
```

In this code you can see the method isAdmin, which calls the method checkSecurity.  Inside of the check security method you can see that it first checks to see if the respective property in the component has already been, if it has then it just directly returns the value otherwise it calls the load security method, which makes and http request.  This http request actual does the work to determine which security levels the user has and returns that information, which is then stored in the respective properties in the component and returned up the chain.

My problem is that the http call is being made numerous times I only ever want 1 http call to be made and I want any other request that comes in to just use or wait for that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out and what I needed was another level of abstraction, so that there was only 1 subscribe being called on the actual http.get call.  I changed the loadSecurity method to be like this.

```
 loadSecurity(): Observable<void> {
        this.loadingMain = Observable.create((observer: any) => {
            if (!this.loading) {
                this.loading = this.http.get(this.baseApiUrl + `loadSecurity`)
                    .map((result) => {
                        var data = this.extractData(result);
                        this.isAdminUser = data.IsAdmin;
                        this.isCommercializationTeamUser = data.IsCommercializationTeam;
                        this.isRedTeamUser = data.IsRedTeam;
                        this.isBlueTeamUser = data.IsBlueTeam;
                        this.isVisitorUser = data.IsVisitor;
                        this.isProjectOwnerTeamUser = data.IsProjectOwnerTeam;
                        this.isProjectTeamUser = data.IsProjectUserTeam;
                        this.isSensoryInsightsTeamUser = data.IsSensoryInsightsTeam;
                    });
                this.loading.subscribe(() => { });
            } else {
                observer.next(this.loading);
                observer.complete();
            }
        });

        return this.loadingMain;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it being called on resolves/Guards? why not just add a flag, to see if checked or not?

```
isAdmin(): Observable<boolean> {
    return (isRoleChecked) ? Observable.of(!!role): this.checkSecurity('isAdminUser');
}
```

Comment: It is being called 10 times before the first call is even being resolved, so just checking to see if it is resolved already won't work (that is what I'm already doing anyway with the check in the checkSecurity method to see if the property is not unassigned.